# GeoServer - Show Maps in a Application Java

Tags: geoserver, java

How can I display a GeoServer's Map inside a Java's Desktop Application?

I would like to display it inside a Java App instead of a browser. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Please explain your question in detail. Which Java Desktop application you are using? You can insert wms link from geoserver to your application. Please go through http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60921/display-shapefile-on-website-java-or-php

Comment: Thanks! :D

So, I who is scheduling this application. I'm using JDK 7 and JavaFX for coding interface and structure respectively. As IDE I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1.

And as said before, I would like to present a map hosted on GeoServer on a screen of my java program and, if possible, without making it simulates a browser.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, you can display a WMS generated map in a desktop app.

Longer answer: It depends, at it's simplest a WMS map (what GeoServer sends you) is just an image generated by a get request to a well known URL scheme. So any app which can request URLs can display WMS maps (so in principal any Java app should be able to do it). However the [WMS specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) is quite long and complicated and the resulting URLs are quite long and complicated, and as your viewer moves around the map or zooms in and out the URL changes in subtle ways. There are various exciting failure modes in WMS which you will need to watch out for.

So my advice would be to go with [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) which provides you with a [framework for making WMS](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wms/) requests and for handling d[rawing maps](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/index.html) on the screen (and handling projections etc).

Comment: Thanks iant! :D
I'll look into that framework right now.